# JavaScript get Current Time not Working Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Hello guys i come here today to share and to fix this code (not fix but to make it work on firefox).
From some how this java script doesn't work on Firefox but it works on Chrome, IE, and Opera.

Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
/* Current Local Time + Updater */
<!-- Begin
var timerID = null;
var timerRunning = false;

function stopclock (){
    if(timerRunning)
        clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerRunning = false;
}

function showtime () {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds()
    var timeValue = "" + hours
    if (timeValue == "0") timeValue = 12;
    timeValue += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes
    timeValue += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds
    document.getElementById("clock").innerText = timeValue;
    timerID = setTimeout("showtime()",1000);
    timerRunning = true;
}

function startclock() {
    stopclock();
    showtime();
}

window.onload=startclock;
</script>
```

This scripts call an ID here is the ID:

```
<span id="clock"></span>
```

(Infos: This is a 24 Hours clock so after mid-day "12:00" keeps on going 13:00 :)

If can some one help me out to make this works on Firefox i will be greatful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `innerText` property on Firefox (the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) property is [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)).

As you don't really need `innerText` or `textContent`, a fast fix would be to change

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerText = timeValue;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = timeValue;
```

Comment: @dystroy For what it's worth, setting `.textContent` is much faster than setting `.innerHTML`, since it doesn't need to do HTML parsing.